# Are the left unitor and right unitor in a symmetric monoidal category related?

Tags: category-theory, axioms, monoidal-categories

Judging from the [axioms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category) of a symmetric monoidal category, can we say anything about the left unitor being related to the right unitor?

We have the morphisms (using notation as nlab) 
$$ \lambda_1 :1 \otimes 1 \rightarrow 1 $$
$$ \rho_1 : 1 \otimes 1 \rightarrow 1$$
It seems desirable to me that 
$$ \lambda_1 =\rho_1 b_{1,1}$$
holds. But this is doesn't seemed to be implied.

The reason for  this is that: wouldn't one want a canonical choice of isomorphism 
$$ 1 \otimes 1 \simeq 1?$$

Comment: @Arnaud You should probably post this as an answer, because it is an answer (and a good one imo)

Comment: @MarkKamsma The nLab doesn't give a proof for the braided case unfortunately. Since the diagrams are a bit too big to reproduce, I ended up posting the relevant references as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, $\lambda_I$ and $\rho_I$ are equal in any monoidal category, and $\lambda_X=\rho_X B_{1,X}$ in any symmetric monoidal category, although this is not entirely obvious. In fact, Mac Lane originally required these as axioms, and also that $\lambda_{A\otimes B}\circ \alpha_{I,A,B}=\lambda_A\otimes B$ and $ A\otimes\rho_B \circ \alpha_{A,B,I} =\rho_{A\otimes B}$, but Kelly showed that all these identities could be deduced from the triangle, pentagon and hexagon diagrams :

> [On MacLane's conditions for coherence of natural associativities, commutativities, etc.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869364900183), G.M. Kelly, 1964, Journal of Algebra 1, pp 397-402

The argument can also be found on the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category#other_coherence_conditions).

Later, Joyal and Street proved that $\lambda_X=\rho_X B_{1,X}$ even holds in braided monoidal categories :

> [Braided tensor categories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870883710558), A. Joyal and R. Street, 1993, Advances in Mathematics 102, pp 20-78